# Click for "more items..." option on context menu in QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, contextmenu

I have implemented a `context menu` project in `QT` by using `C++` . I want to have maximum of 5 elements in the context menu to be shown at first. But it has a total of 15 elements and I want user to click on "More items..." or some kind of "Down" arrow button so that the context menu gets expanded to show more than 5 elements. Is it possible? If yes, I would appreciate some pointer in the right direction. Thanks.

Please note that the way I am trying to implement it, the context menu disappears on click of More items... So that is not what I want.

//Code

```
void myWidget::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)
{
    QMenu menu(this);
    menu.addAction(new QAction("Action 1", this));
    menu.addAction(new QAction("Action 2", this));
    menu.addAction(new QAction("Action 3", this));
    menu.addAction(new QAction("Action 4", this));
    menu.addAction(new QAction("Action 5", this));
    QAction *moreItems = new QAction("More items...", this);
    QObject::connect(moreItems , SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(moreItemsClicked()));
    menu.addAction(moreItems);

    menu.exec(event->globalPos());
}

void myWidget::moreItemsClicked()
{
    //Now what! Need help!
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest you to not use macros `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` or if you want to use them - always check connection result. Your intension was to connect to `clicked` signal of `QAction`, but there is [**no such signal**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#signals).
If you will use function pointer instead of `SIGNAL`  - you will get compilation error which is always better then runtime assertion.

Regarding question itself, please consider simple multilevel menu:

[image]

But if you really want, you can extend menu in this way:

```
void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent* event)
    {
        auto menu = new QMenu(this);
        menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 1", this));
        menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 2", this));
        menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 3", this));
        menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 4", this));
        menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 5", this));
        QAction* moreItems = new QAction("More items...", this);
        const auto connection_result = connect(moreItems, &QAction::triggered, [=]() 
            {
            menu->removeAction(moreItems);
            menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 6", this));
            menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 7", this));

            menu->exec(event->globalPos());
            });
        Q_ASSERT(connection_result);
        Q_UNUSED(connection_result);

        menu->addAction(moreItems);
        menu->exec(event->globalPos());
    }
```

You will be forced to reopen menu cause it will be hidden after click.

Also, menu must be created on heap to be available inside lambda. That force us to take care about memory leaks. To do that you can add this connection:

```
connect(menu, &QMenu::triggered, menu, &QMenu::deleteLater);
```

But in that case we need to rely on connections order since we expect that menu is still alive when lambda is executed, which is not the best. Or call `QMenu::deleteLater` from each action which is not good either.

So I would just recreate extended menu like this:

```
QMenu* CreateContextMenu(bool is_extended, QAction* extra_action, QWidget* parent)
    {
        auto menu = new QMenu(parent);

        const auto connection_result = connect(menu, &QMenu::triggered, menu, &QMenu::deleteLater);
        Q_ASSERT(connection_result);
        Q_UNUSED(connection_result);

        menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 1", this));
        menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 2", this));
        menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 3", this));
        menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 4", this));
        menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 5", this));

        if (is_extended)
        {
            menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 6", this));
            menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 7", this));
        } else {
            menu->addAction(extra_action);
        }

        return menu;
    }

    void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent* event)
    {
        QAction* moreItems = new QAction("More items...", this);
        const auto connection_result = connect(moreItems, &QAction::triggered, [=]() {
            auto extended_menu = CreateContextMenu(true, nullptr, this);
            extended_menu->exec(event->globalPos());
        });

        Q_ASSERT(connection_result);
        Q_UNUSED(connection_result);

        auto menu = CreateContextMenu(false, moreItems, this);
        menu->exec(event->globalPos());
        
    }
```

You can also improve interface of CreateContextMenu, since first and second argument can't be present in same time, probably using `std::variant`. But I decided that it will be offtopic.